# Flutter always need to Restart or flutter clean

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is my flutter unable to display the widget that I wrote at the beginning of the `F5 debug` flutter or the `flutter run` in command line. My Flutter shows a previous Widget and also a previous error even though I deleted my code. I always have to `hot reload` or `flutter clean` to get a Widget or data that matches what I wrote.

**Note:** Before this happens. My project got a lot of errors due to `flutter upgrade`I tried trying for days to justify it to replace the versions but the exact can't be solved. So I decided to reinstall my flutter. Please help me. I was frustrated enough.

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at D:\FlutterSDK\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (7 days ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: D:\Rts\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at D:\AndroidSDK\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM A205F • RR8M512EJ8X • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Thank you

Comment: what is a complete command line? just `flutter run`? what if you add `-v`?

Comment: @pskink too long if i put here. but my code is going according to plan even though it takes a lot of time. can you explain why this happened?

Comment: what is too long? did you run `flutter run -v`? if so, what are the last, say 20, lines of log?

Comment: @pskink here the link to see https://codeshare.io/2Kq9w8

Comment: and what happens if you press `r` ?

Comment: I ran into something similar on Linux and the issue turned out to be that my projects were being accessed via a symlink instead of a regular path. The symlink was throwing things off.

As soon as I got rid of the symlink, it all straightened out.

Comment: @pskink i got reset. Is this the only method for this problem for my problem?

Comment: @scottstoll2017 So how do you get rid of the symlink?

Comment: so you dont want to use `"hot reload"` feature (triggered by pressing `r` key)? honestly i am a bit lost here...

Comment: @pskink Not like that. I mean. I'm just confused why my flutter after upgrading to the latest version has to hot reload first. because before I reinstall it only with debug `f5` or `flutter run` it is as I expected. without having to add `hot reload` first :)

Comment: ok, i see it now... i thought that hot reload is not working at all...

Comment: You can bypass the symlink by using the full path instead of the symlink shortcut

Comment: [These commands might need for you](https://androidride.com/flutter-create-new-project-command-line-options/)

Answer (score 1):

Try `flutter clean`, followed by `flutter channel stable`. This will reset the build directory, and ensure you're on the stable branch of Flutter.  Try `flutter run -v` and report the output, please.